# Bluetooth high quality support gone in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 14.04

I have a bluetooth speaker (http://www.sound2go.net/produkte/bigbass-plus).

In ubuntu 13.10 I could go to the audio settings and choose the bluetooth mode (Telephony - Low Quality, of High Quality).

Like shown on this picture:

[image]

In Ubuntu 14.04 the speaker still works, but the sound quality is really bad. Just like it was when the low quality mode was selected in Ubuntu 13.10.

And the option to choose the mode is gone from the sound settings.

Like shown on this picture:

[image]

I searched every place I could think of and did not find it elsewhere.

How can I get decent sound quality with my speaker in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that it is a bug and the device was not properly set up.
After some trial of removing and re-adding the device it worked.

I had to pair the speaker with another device (I used my phone) to properly make ubuntu re-add id. I also explicitly selected that the device was an audio device when adding it.

Now I have high quality support again, it is available in the sound settings.

I don't know exactly what finally fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Granted!Instead of changing to A2DP on sounds settings go to settings on your bluetooth device admin and change it there. ;)